# How can I store icons into my local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects structure like this:

```
{
  id: 0,
  icon: <ShoppingCartIcon />,
  label: 'Groceries',
  content: ['grocery list', 'test']
},
```

The icon is imported from Materials UI. The icon shows up next to the label when it is rendered on my page. The user can add new labels and choose an icon to go with it. I am setting my state to add the new object, along with the icon that they chose.

```
handleAddIcon = (icon) => {
    let iconValue = icon.icon;
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(iconValue))
    let activeTab = this.state.activeTab;
    let tabs = [...this.state.tabs];
    tabs[activeTab].icon = iconValue;
    this.setState({
      tabs,
      selectIcon: false,
      newCategorySelected: false
    } , () => localStorage.setItem('tabs', JSON.stringify(this.state.tabs)))

  }
```

But when I try to retrieve this from my local storage, the icon value is coming back as null. I'm assuming this is because the icon is an import?

```
(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tabs')).length != 0) ? tabs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tabs')) : tabs = []
console.log(tabs.map(id => id.icon)) // all values are null, and no icon can render on the page
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: maybe confirm that your setItem runs?

Comment: It is. But when I try to log the value of my icon I am getting `key: null props: {} ref: null type: {type: {…}, compare: null} _owner: null _store: {} [[Prototype]]: Object
` (sorry I can't copy the whole thing, it would be a lot, but basically it all comes out as null). I tried to store it as a string value, but then it just returns `[object] [object]`

Answer (score 3):

You can't store a react component in local storage as that would require "stringifying" the instance of component which will only ever give you `[object] [object]`.

What you need to do is store some string key or some codified representation of the icon which you can store. Upon retrieval you can render the relevant icon.

You need to change the object to store the icon name / id / some representation of which icon is being selected.

```js
{
  id: 0,
  iconId: 'ShoppingCartIcon1',
  label: 'Groceries',
  content: ['grocery list', 'test']
}
```

Given you are using `@material-ui/icons` you can use the icon names as they key. You will need to change it so that when a user selects an icon you store the icon name.

```js
handleAddIcon = (icon) => {
    let iconName = icon.name; // get the icon name / id here
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(iconValue))
    let activeTab = this.state.activeTab;
    let tabs = [...this.state.tabs];
    tabs[activeTab].iconName = iconName; // change this to rely on the icon name
    // ...rest

  }
```

When you render the icon, instead of directly relying on the icon to be in the state you can render the icon depending on which name was selected.

```js
// on option is just to check for each icon

  tabs.map((tab) => (
    <Tab>
      {tab.iconName === "ShoppingCart" && <ShoppingCartIcon />}
      {tab.iconName === "Alarm" && <AlarmIcon />}
      // ...so on
    </Tab>
  );
```

If there are too many icon options you could create a map between the icon name and the component so something like:

```js
// on option is just to check for each icon
const nameToIconMap = {
  ShoppingCart: <ShoppingCartIcon />,
  Alarm: <AlarmIcon />,
  // soo on
}

  tabs.map((tab) => (
    <Tab>
      // reference the name inside the render like so
      {nameToIconMap[tab.iconName]}
    </Tab>
  );
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense, but forgive my ignorance, if I store the icon as a string, how do I render it as a Component?

Comment: Are you using `@material-ui/icons` package?

Comment: Yes I am. I imported a bunch and have them all stored in an array of objects. And then when the user selects an icon, that icon component gets added to the object I wrote in my post, which is what I'm mapping through and trying to render. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I have updated the answer to add more details around how you would implement this hope that helps